# Adding border with width to UIView show small background outside

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, xib

I'm trying to add circle border to a `UIView` with green background, I created simple `UIView` subclass with borderWidth, cornerRadius and borderColor properties and I'm setting it from storyboard.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            } else {
                return UIColor.clear
            }
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    } 

}
```

But when I compile and run an app or display it in InterfaceBuilder I can see a line outside the border that is still there (and is quite visible on white background).

[image]

This `RoundedView` with green background, frame 10x10, corner radius = 5 is placed in corner of plain `UIImageView` (indicates if someone is online or not). You can see green border outside on both UIImageView and white background.

[image]

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: (1) You didn't include any code or explanation on how the UIImageView is positioned inside the UIView, or any constraints. (2) You mentioned IB and compile, but how about when you actually run the app? I'm seeing all the right things (both code and your IB screenshot) for the view itself... and if the UIImageView has no border (and a clear background) you should be good.

Comment: (1) Updated my answer, this green dot is `RoundedView` with border, it has this strange border issue - it's just placed over `UIImageView` (2) Of course, compile and run - this border is visible in both simulator and real device around green dot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is relying on the layer to draw your border and round the corners. So you are not in charge of the result. You gave it a green background, and now you are seeing the background "stick out" at the edge of the border. And in any case, rounding the corners is a really skanky and unreliable way to make a round view. To make a round view, make a round *mask*.

So, the way to make your badge is to take complete charge of what it is drawn: *you* draw a green *circle* in the center of a *white* background, and *mask* it all with a larger circle to make the border.

Here is a Badge view that will do precisely what you're after, with no artifact round the outside:

```
class Badge : UIView {
    class Mask : UIView {
        override init(frame:CGRect) {
            super.init(frame:frame)
            self.isOpaque = false
            self.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
            con.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(origin:.zero, size:rect.size))
        }
    }
    let innerColor : UIColor
    let outerColor : UIColor
    let innerRadius : CGFloat
    var madeMask = false
    init(frame:CGRect, innerColor:UIColor, outerColor:UIColor, innerRadius:CGFloat) {
        self.innerColor = innerColor
        self.outerColor = outerColor
        self.innerRadius = innerRadius
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        con.setFillColor(outerColor.cgColor)
        con.fill(rect)
        con.setFillColor(innerColor.cgColor)
        con.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(
            x: rect.midX-innerRadius, y: rect.midY-innerRadius,
            width: 2*innerRadius, height: 2*innerRadius))
        if !self.madeMask {
            self.madeMask = true // do only once
            self.mask = Mask(frame:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:rect.size))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this with a sample setting as follows:

```
let v = Badge(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:100, width:16, height:16), 
              innerColor: .green, outerColor: .white, innerRadius: 5)
self.view.addSubview(v)
```

It looks fine. Adjust the parameters as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain me why this is 'skanky and unreliable way' to do it? Also, do you know why this green border appears?

Comment: I've shown you the right way. It works, and it solves the problem you posed. Try it and see.

Comment: Yes, it's great, thanks. I just wanted to know the reason for this border to occur

Comment: You don't need a _reason_. I explained that by asking the layer to do the drawing _for_ you, you are taking your hands off and just accepting whatever it does. So what it does is what it does — if that's the road you choose to go down. The solution is: don't do that. Draw it yourself. And I even showed you how.

Comment: I'd like to know ***why*** it happens, too. The reason for this is that I want my circular-view-with-border to be able to animate between color values, both inner and outer. Without a highly complex color calculation scheme (done for me by Apple with layer animations), I'm not sure how to do that with your solution. By not knowing ***how*** it works, getting to my desired end point is harder. Or to ask it another way: how would you add color-change animations to this solution?

Comment: I wasn't the OP. I was mainly commenting on you slapping down the OP for being curious. You appear to have taken his comment as arguing with you. Whether he was or not (and I didn't read it that way), ***I*** think the **why** of the original question is interesting, too. If the answer is, "it's a private implementation, so we don't know exactly how it works," then fine. But the OP's initial comment was asking what I thought were good follow-on questions, without challenging your answer in any way. (And I'm currently implementing your answer, so thanks.)

Comment: @mbm29414 Nevertheless, if you have an actual question about color animation, please do ask it as a separate question. Feel free to blip me here when you do.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I'm under a deadline and the immediate nature of the transition is good enough. I hope I can get some time to circle back to this at some point...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using a UIBezierPath and adding to the view's layer:

```
        let strokePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, cornerRadius: view.frame.width / 2)
        let stroke = CAShapeLayer()
        stroke.frame = bounds
        stroke.path = strokePath.cgPath
        stroke.fillColor = .green.cgColor
        stroke.lineWidth = 1.0
        stroke.strokeColor = .white.cgColor
        view.layer.insertSublayer(stroke, at: 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier fix might be to just mask it like this:

```
let mask = UIView()
mask.backgroundColor = .black
mask.frame = yourCircleView.bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.1, left: 0.1, bottom: 0.1, right: 0.1))
mask.layer.cornerRadius = mask.height * 0.5
yourCircleView.mask = mask
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with gradients. 
Just seting the backgroundColor of your circle  as gradient.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    //define colors
    gradientLayer.colors = [<<your_bgc_color>>>>,  <<border__bgc__color>>]
    //define locations of colors as NSNumbers in range from 0.0 to 1.0
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.7]
    //define frame
    gradientLayer.frame = self.classView.bounds

    self.classView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

[MyImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI9N6.png)